# Published app in google play is gone with no reason

Tags: store, playback

Our app which was published and stable for more than 4 weeks is gone from google play jus few hours ago the app was fine today . The google play console has no errors whatsoever .

[image: Google console state]

when i try to look for the app using the package name it says

> We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should contact Google Play support.

Comment: You maybe right !! but isn't this the place to ensure that there is no technical problem from my side like a wrong package name ???

Comment: The requirements for an app to be on GP change all the time. Issues are highlighted in the console, it might be worth going through all sections again.

Comment: @RichardNixon exactly thats whats driving me insane is that there are no issues at all in the console the app is live and published

Comment: Is you app paid for btw? If so you need an address on your main profile I believe.

Comment: if you mean is my app paid or free than my app is free to download from playstore and if you mean is the developer account is paid yes it is .  @RichardNixon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the same problem with app that have 300+ users
I've contacted support, cause this looks like a google play problem/error

Same problem here

https://community.adobe.com/t5/adobe-comp/cant-find-adobe-comp-on-goole-play/m-p/10956298?page=1

Comment: Seems like it is a problem from google side because i have checked every possible case and everything looks fine i have contacted them and let's hope for the best thanks @Razikus

Comment: Hopefuly! Can you share the link for your app?

Funniest thing is that i tried over proxy (https://www.kproxy.com/) and it shows me the app

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pc.com.pocketcarage&hl=en

Comment: Same for you! I've tried over kproxy.com and it shows your application. Are you for example tracking your users location?

Comment: Yes . what does that mean.

Comment: I saw information here, that it can be related to that
https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotterwu/comments/b6juea/wizards_unite_disappeared_from_google_play/
But of course - better to wait for support answer

Comment: For sure, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

It generally happens when users are constantly giving low ratings to your app or you have very fewer downloads even after a very long time of publishing your app. If none of them are the cases then you should contact google support at the given link. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en#topic=3450769

Comment: Non of what you mentioned is a problem as i have only 2 or 3 people who rated my app

Comment: but even if i have fewer downloads does that mean my app is gone ! because i cant even find it when i click on "View on google play" inside the play cosnole